# How to safely install ubuntu studio on second partition where kali linux is now?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have still (?) from G parted checking installed Ubuntu 18.04 on sda1 and KALI on sda2.  Dual boot is not working anymore system goes straight to Ubuntu. 
How can I install safelly UBUNTU STUDIO on sda2 insteda KALI so that system will boot? Also how to make rescue USB in case non booting?

Comment: Do you really just want to repair install on sda1, or still install another Ubuntu on sda2? You may be able to use Boot-Repair to repair install. And only use Something Else install option and choose sda2 (change button) to install to sda2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you have copied off all data from Kali's partition you might find useful.
2) Delete all the contents of sda2 after booting from the Ubuntu in sda1  .
Create a LiveUSB with [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/download) after [confirming the download of Studio matches its checksum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM).
3) Shutdown and then reboot with the Studio Live USB.
4) Choose install and select Something Else when it asks for where to install it.
5) Should GRUB2 not give you the option to boot Studio after install completes and the PC reboots, perform a Boot Repair with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I downloaded and installed boot repair on USB and it solved the dual boot problem  with KALI. I will make  image of the disk with clonezilla , and than install STUDIO as per your instructions.